# Number of ODE Events changes with varying condition simple ODE

Tags: matlab, events, ode, ode45

I have the following simple ODE:

```
dx/dt=-1
```

With initial condition x(0)=5, I am interested in when x(t)==1.  So I have the following events function:

```
function [value,isterminal,direction] = test_events(t,x)
    value = x-1;
    isterminal = 0;
    direction = 0;
end
```

This should produce an event at t=4.  However, if I run the following code I get two events, one at t=4, and one at the nearby location t=4+5.7e-14:

```
options = odeset('Events',@test_events);
sol = ode45(@(t,x)-1,[0 10],5,options);
fprintf('%.16f\n',sol.xe)
% 4.0000000000000000
% 4.0000000000000568
```

If I run similar codes to find when x(t)==0 or x(t)==-1 (value = x; or value = x+1; respectively), I have only one event.  Why does this generate two events?

UPDATE: If the options structure is changed to the following:

```
options = odeset('Events',@test_events,'RelTol',1e-4);
```

...then the ODE only returns one event at t=4+5.7e-14.  If 'RelTol' is set to 1e-5, it returns one event at t=4.  If 'RelTol' is set to 1e-8, it returns the same two events as the default ('RelTol'=1e-3).  Additionally, changing the initial condition from x(0)=5 to x(0)=4 produces a single event, but setting x(0)=4 and 'RelTol'=1e-8 produces two events.

UPDATE 2: Observing the sol.x and sol.y outputs (t and x, respectively), the time progresses as integers [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7...], and x progresses as integers up until x(t=5) like so: [5 4 3 2 1 1.11e-16 -1.000 -2.000...].  This indicates that there is something that occurs between t=4 and t=5 that creates a 'bump' in the ODE solution.  Why?

Comment: Have a look at 'RelTol' and 'AbsTol' options. If I set options = odeset('Reltol',1e-5,'Events',@test_events); I have only one event at 'x-1'

Comment: I too get only one event by setting RelTol to 1e-5.  However, I still don't understand why this should impact anything with such a simple and well-scaled ODE.  I will update the question to include this information.

Comment: the ode solver has a limited precision, which you can change through those two properties. The t values you get are the same for the solver. It can not tell them apart.

Comment: This still leaves the following problems:
-Stricter tolerance can decrease solver accuracy in many cases.  With a simple case like this, stricter tolerance should be unnecessary and a completely arbitrary choice
-Setting RelTol=1e-8 produces the same solution as the default RelTol=1e-3
-Changing the definition of 'value' in @test_events or changing the initial condition can vary results (RelTol should not impact these differently)
I'll update the question to include this information

Comment: You  could also look at the internal sampling points that are contained in the sol object. It could happen that in some of the examples there is one close to 4, however as the step size should be quite large, it should be a low-probability event.

Comment: I just looked into this, interestingly the sol.y output reads as follows: [5 4 3 2 1 1.11e-16 -1.000 -2.000...].  So something is happening between t=4 and t=5 that is adjusting the output so it isn't an exactly straight line.  Running without the events function produces the same result.  I will update the question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

One speculation that might explain how rounding errors could occur in this simple problem: The solution is interpolated between the internal steps using the evaluations `k_n` of the ODE derivatives function, also called "dense output". The theoretical form is

```
b_1(u)k_1 + b_2(u)k_2 + ...b_s(u)k_s
```

where `0 <= u<= 1` it the parameter over the interval between the internal points, that is, `t = (1-u)*t_k+u*t_{k+1}`.

The coefficient polynomials are non-trivial. While in the example all the `k_i=1` are constant, the evaluation of the sum `b_1(u)+...+b_s(u)` can accumulate rounding errors that become visible in the solution value close to a root, even if `y_k` and `y_{k+1}` are exact. In that range of accumulated floating point noise, the value might oscillate around the root, leading to the detection of multiple zero crossings.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful answer.  I have thought about this a bit but I'm not sure I entirely understand.  However, I will address what I can understand: if there are multiple crossings of the root of the events function, then wouldn't that mean that I would need an odd number of events to satisfy value(t=0) > 0 and value(t=t_end) < 0?  Additionally, shouldn't imposing a direction constraint result in a single event in this case?  I checked this latter idea, and setting direction = -1 does not solve the issue.

Comment: That would be the case if the interpolating polynomials would fit together completely continuously. I do not know what exactly happens, but I think that due to floating point errors there are gaps. But to know what exactly happens one would have to dig deeply into the intermediary results and code, as far as that is possible. One could start with plotting the solution close to the root, using the evaluation of `sol` to get the values of the interpolating polynomials.